# How to get Salesforce ID for a custom object in SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I have a scenario to list out *available custom objects* in my org and Needs to know how to get Salesforce 15 digit ID of an object(Custom) by using SOQL query like an

For example:

```
select id from customOBJMetaData where name like '%Objname%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also query object names in regular SOQL from `EntityDefinition` but there isn't a specific filter on whether it's custom or not. The field `DurableId` will return a 15-character ID for any custom object and a string for any standard object, so one possible query is:

```
SELECT DurableId, QualifiedApiName FROM EntityDefinition
WHERE DurableId LIKE '0______________'
```

Avoids the need to run to the Tooling API. Anyone else here have better filter ideas to just return custom?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute tooling queries via SOQL. The following works fine in the Developer Console:

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM CustomObject
```

If you want to access this data via Apex, you'll need to call out to the Tooling API with the same query.

Comment: I need to use this in vf page, Is that not possible?

Comment: There are plenty of resources that say how you can access the Tooling API from a Visualforce Page. That's not the question you asked here.

Comment: Please help me to get resolved from that

Comment: Do some research. Make an attempt. Ask a separate question if you get stuck.